# Sharepoint - Showing calendar events in multiple calendars in diff't sub-sites

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, aggregate

I am trying to show events from a calendar in the main site to a calendar in a sub-site of the main site (or vice-versa)...I can't alter any server files or use custom-built web parts...is there anyway to do this w/ OOTB moss 2007?

Comment: AFIK sharepoint 2007 does not have the mechanism for rollup/downs built in

Answer (score 0):

Altering Server files is a big no-no anyway, so that's good :-D. YOu could try using SharePoint designer to create a so-called aggregation webpart, pulling data from all sites in the site collection (which of course get security trimmed by sharepoint, so people see only what they are allowed to see).

YOu can create use a DataFormWebPart in SharePoint designer to build an aggregation webpart. This is still ootb, but allows you to configure the datasource: i.e. have the datasource query the entire site collection for calendar items, then display them in a list. Disdplay them in a "new" calendar will be a lot of work though.

There is no way to "copy" or deisgnate specific calendar items to be visible in specific other calendars, this will take custom code.

Comment: thanks everyone for your comments/suggestions...i think for now i'll go w/ the CQWP and just show it as a list...w/ the date in the title..  This seems to be a very popular question/issue while doing my research...hopefully someday that will be an inclusion for OOTB functionality :)

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly OOTB MOSS 2007, but I recenlty wrote an article about syncing any list using a simple workflow. As a Calendar is just a list it works for that as well and it maintains the Calendar look and feel.

[Check it out here](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/12/automatically-synchronise-sharepoint.html), it works great and deals with attachments as well. As it is part of a workflow you can add your own logic easily, e.g. Only sync calendar events that have field 'x' set to 'y'.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to point out that [RSSBus](http://www.rssbus.com) Web Part can handle a task like this with minimal code. This, although not ootb is quite simple and does not require use of SharePoint Designer.

```
<rsb:import lib="RSSBus.SpsOps"/>
<rsb:set attr="url" value="http://mysharepointsite/subSite/"/>
<rsb:set attr="list" value="Calendar"/>
<rsb:set attr="user" value="someuser"/>
<rsb:set attr="password" value="theirpassword"/>

  <rsb:call op="spsListItems">
    [[sp:name]]</br>
  </rsb:call>
```

The code above can be placed within the RSSBus Web Part on the main site and through the use of "SpsOps" have access to all lists/items on all sites/subsites.

-S